# Junit : add handling logic when exception is not expected

Tags: exception, junit

I am trying to print the stack trace of the exception.

However, for negative test case, only the unexpected exception is printed.

I am using the @Rule ExpectedException to do the exception detection.

I don't know how to add handling logic in case an unexpected exception is thrown.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    thrown.expect(MyException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("expected message");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply catch the exception within your test method, and then print the stack trace? (and then even rethrow it if you want).

Comment: I can do it, but I just want to know if there is any other solution for that.

Comment: @franziga, what's your point - is it just theoretical interest, or do you want to actually achieve something concrete?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try implementing [`WatchmanTest.failed`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatchman.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Franziga, you might try [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) to satisfy your theoretical interest:

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {

    catchException(obj).doSomethingExceptional();
    log(caughtException());
    assertTrue(caughtException() instanceof MyException.class);
    assertEquals("expected message", caughtException().getMessage());

}
```